# ACF meta_query field treated as "0" resulting in false negative search when testing ranges

Tags: meta-query

I'm struggling a bit with building a correct meta_query search.

The query in question that fails:

```
if ($data['size']['size_from'] && $data['size']['size_to']) {
                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'talent_data_size_size_from',
                        'value'   => $data['size']['size_from'],
                        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                        'compare' => '>='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'talent_data_size_size_to',
                        'value'   => $data['size']['size_to'],
                        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                        'compare' => '<='
                    )
                );
            }
```

It works for the most part, but when I have a post that only has a value in "size_from" it breaks.
[image: Post example]

So lets say I make a search for size 5 to 15.
First condition will be true because 48 > 5.
Second condition will also be true because 0 (no value) < 15. This is a false positive, because "size_to" should not be able to be lower than "size_from".

So I know why it breaks, but for the life of me I can't seem to find a clever solution. Maybe I just cant see the forest through the trees at this point.

Comment: Ended up filtering out the false positives post query. Not the solution I would have liked, but it works.

Comment: Can you not add another comparison clause? One that specifies that the value must be > 0?